# Is jsonb conversion to text deterministic?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

This is the short version of an overly long [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487208/efficiently-group-many-fields-including-large-text-and-jsonb) that sadly attracted no answers.

Is it possible, given two jsonb variables x and y, to have both
 1. (x = y) yield true, and
 2. (x::text = y::text) yield false

I ask this question because it appears there is no promised order in which a jsonb object will be unpacked into a string. I'd just like to be sure this is the case.

Thanks in advance for feedback!

Edit:

The original question covers the "why" for this question, but the skinny is that I hope to group data in different rows based upon a hash of many columns represented as text, some of which are jsonb.

I don't care which way the object comes in or which way it gets unpacked, but I do care if two jsonb fields which are equivalent as jsonb are not equivalent as text strings.

As it *seems* I cannot count on text representations to be presented in the same way, I've normalized out the jsonb field to a separate table with the jsonb field set as a unique index.

And if I write more here... this question will approach the length of the one it derives from!

Comment: Deterministic? Certainly. Predictable? I'd say so. Reliable? No, shouldn't count on that.

Comment: @Bergi, your comment confuses me -- if it is deterministic, then it's pretty reliable, provided one doesn't care what that ordering is. We seem to be using that word differently.

Comment: I meant to express that there is a [*deterministic* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_system) (relying on the state of the DBMS, unlikely involving randomness) given by the Postgres code, but that you should not *rely* on a particular (undocumented) behaviour as it may be subject to changes with any version upgrade.

Comment: @Bergi, If it's guaranteed to be deterministic in the unpacking to text, then actually that means I (for my purposes) could rely on it, because I hear you saying that any one version of Postgres will do it the same way every time. That might change after an upgrade, but it'd change for both 'x' and 'y' -- leaving me still happily seeing them always equal, both as json and as text. Am I making sense?

Comment: Haha or are you saying that the rules might change so that the jsonb gets unpacked in a possibly random-ish manner? In which case, yeah, that'd be a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: Yes, I mean that it might change to a different deterministic algorithm that will yield different results for `x` and `y` - based on their memory address, property addition order during construction, or whatnot.

Comment: I guess you should consider using the `json` datatype instead which explicitly preserves the textual representation, including order.

Comment: Simply it is a good practice not to rely on undocumented properties, even they seem obvious.

Comment: Thanks to both @Bergi and klin for thoughts -- Bergi, yours seems to nail the technical answer to my question. It's deterministic (and therefore reliable as of this writing) but cannot be relied upon to be so in the future. Should I just accept klin's answer? Or wait for Bergi to post something I can accept? Many thanks to both for thoughts.

Comment: @Wellspring Feel free to accept Klin's answer, I don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally the order is not deterministic because of the [JSON object definition:](http://www.json.org/)

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Practically it appears that objects are sorted by length of keys and then alphabetically:

```
with example(col) as (
values 
    ('{"cc": 1, "ab": 1, "a": 1, "aa": 1, "b": 2, "abc": 1}'::jsonb)
)

select col::text
from example

                          col                          
-------------------------------------------------------
 {"a": 1, "b": 2, "aa": 1, "ab": 1, "cc": 1, "abc": 1}
(1 row)
```

Note that this behavior is undocumented and may change in future releases (though it may seem unlikely).

Comment: The longer question covered the need, but in short it had to do with producing a hash on the text. Maybe there's a better way to accomplish that, but that was the overarching question I didn't get an answer to. I perhaps need to clarify my question, as order is not a concern for me.

Comment: It is clear to me that order is not important for you, but when something is ordered then it is predictable.

Comment: @Wellspring - I'm also looking to create a deterministic hash of a jsonb column, what did you end up doing in this case? thanks!

Comment: @MattyF I stored the jsonb in a table and ensured uniqueness on that jsonb column. I then used the PK field (uuid) as my "hash". This probably sounds a bit (or a lot) like a hack, but it served my purposes well enough.